# JQuery - divs and styles

Tags: jquery, html, coding-style

make order
            portfolie
            contacts
            vacancies
            about company

I add style for it in jquery-script:

```
        $('#head_menu a').each(
            function()
            {
               $(this).addClass('menu_part'); 
            }
        )
```

And style **menu_part**

```
.menu_part
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url(../images/bg_menu.png);
    float:left;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

And now I want to change style if part of the menu clicked:

```
        $('#head_menu a').click(
            function(e)
            {
                $(this).removeClass('menu_part').addClass('menu_chose');
            });
```

**menu_chose** style:

```
 .menu_chose
    {
        background-image: url(../images/bg_menu_hover.png);                            
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

Everything is good, but after clicking only text-color changes to white, but background-image is still old, why?

---

**upd**

Images paths are right. Here is another style:

```
.menu_part:hover
{
    background-image: url(../images/bg_menu_hover.png);
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And it works greatly, when mouse is over.

Comment: Choosed really should be "chosen" -- English is funny that way.

Comment: Are you completely sure that both images are different - if they're the same, then you woul not see a change. try swapping the urls of the images over, to see if you get the default appearance as 'choosed'

Comment: Yes - English is so funny, that many native English speakers have trouble with it. I'm assuming, however, that @Ockonal is not a native English speaker, and giving him (or her) the appropriate amount of slack.

Comment: I wasn't complaining, just pointing out the correct usage, precisely because I assumed that the OP was not a native English-speaker and would like to know the correct usage.

Comment: My apologies if I appeared to criticise your post, helping non native speakers is good - especially as they're the ones that are most willing to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this code:

```
    $('#head_menu a').each(
        function()
        {
           $(this).addClass('menu_part'); 
        }
    )
```

Can be simplified as:

```
    $('#head_menu a').addClass('menu_part');
```

Secondly, from the looks of it you are adding the class 'menu_choosed' in your click event handler, whilst your stylesheet actually has the style 'menu_chosed' (only one 'o'). If you change both to 'menu_chosen' the problem should hopefully disappear!

Comment: Sorry, I've edited code. There aren't problems with styles names.

Comment: You've accepted the answer - does that mean this was the problem after all?